# npm install failure with npm ERR

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install gulp globally，so I use this command   ，

```
npm install gulp -g
```

then throw this error：

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path E:\nodejs\node_global\gulp
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'E:\nodejs\node_global\gulp'
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     H:\npm-debug.log
```

It seems that the error occurs because when it wants to open an director ，in fact it was an file.I checked for the node_global director and found an file named gulp.cmd and a file named gulp too.So there may be conflict between them.

Comment: What is E:? Try using the regular program files folder. More solutions may be here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6861

Comment: I solve this by change configure.It seems that  I config the npm with cache  and prefix in the same director ...Maybe bu incident. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is an simple problem.I set the config of npm with this

```
cache=E:\nodejs\node_global
prefix=E:\nodejs\node_global
```

The cache and prefix should not be placed in same director.May be I just change it by accident.Happy coding:)